# CASE expression for NULL condition is not working

Tags: sql, case, sqlanywhere

I have an SQL query where the `case` expression is not working because I am getting the `NULL` value.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
select 
td.reportEndDate,
    CASE td.originalLinearAirDate
    WHEN NULL THEN '12345678'
    END As originalLinearAirDate
from 
FROM DBA.Telecast td 
where id = 2
order by
td.reportEndDate,
originalLinearAirDate;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: that is a case _expression_, not a "statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isnull

```
select 
td.reportEndDate,
    CASE WHEN td.originalLinearAirDate IS NULL THEN '19000101'
         ELSE td.originalLinearAirDate 
    END As originalLinearAirDate
from 
FROM DBA.Telecast td 
where id = 2
order by
td.reportEndDate,
originalLinearAirDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()` :

```
SELECT td.reportEndDate, 
       COALESCE(td.originalLinearAirDate, '12345678') AS originalLinearAirDate -- Use default date instead of '12345678'
FROM DBA.Telecast td 
WHERE id = 2
ORDER BY td.reportEndDate, originalLinearAirDate;
```

In your `case` expression you didn't specified `ELSE` part hence you got `NULL`.

However, case expression will only return one type. So, you should check code or do necessary conversation.

Comment: While applying this, I am getting this error, SQL Anywhere Error -1001014: Data conversion failed

Comment: @Aditya. . . `12345678` is not equals to date-time type. So, you should have a something that matches date-time type.

Comment: Hi there is one check if null then print '12345678' . If some value is there then print the same value

Comment: @Aditya. . . That not possible you should have a single data type in one column. For that case you would need to do conversation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `NULL` comparison.  The comparison is never true, even when used from comparison in a `CASE` expression.

If you wanted to do this using `CASE`, then you need to use `IS NULL`:

```
(CASE WHEN td.originalLinearAirDate IS NULL
      THEN '12345678'
 END) As originalLinearAirDate
```

If you want to return the original value in this case, you need an `ELSE`:

```
(CASE WHEN td.originalLinearAirDate IS NULL
      THEN '12345678'
      ELSE td.originalLinearAirDate 
 END) As originalLinearAirDate
```

Note that this will return an error if the column is really a `DATE`, because `'12345678'` cannot be converted to a date.

This version is better expressed using `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(td.originalLinearAirDate, '12345678')
```